Is there a way with Azure Devops Pipeline to trigger on pull request completion?
I have a pipeline that needs to run on a cron on main, but also trigger when a pull request is merged into main. There is a trigger for this, however, I would need the pull request number to pass as a variable for a script to run against.
Are there any more options? besides a webhook to trigger on pull request completion, but also access the pull request number? Without relying on a git commit messages.
I have explored the following, however, I would prefer the pipeline configuration to contain this logic:

Azure Devops Webhook - which can run if a pull request is completed.

